# How I can create animation in Xamarin.Forms using MVVM

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I want to create an animation triggered when pressing the icon

How I can i do it in while following the MVVM pattern.

**View**

```
<Image Source="ic_test.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="16,24,16,0">
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding AnimationTestCommand}" />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Comment: which animation you want on image tap?

Comment: @ZiyadGodil  When I push the icon, she should zoom.

Comment: See my answer hope it helps you :)

Comment: @ZiyadGodil  Thank you

Comment: You are welcome !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom Image and put animation on tap like below:

```
public class CustomImage : Image
{
    public CustomImage() : base()
    {
        const int _animationTime = 10;
        var iconTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        iconTap.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var btn = (CustomImage)sender;
                await btn.ScaleTo(5, _animationTime);
                //await btn.ScaleTo(1, _animationTime);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Track();
            }
        };

    }
}
```